# MYSQL JOINS with 3 tables

Tags: mysql

TABLE A, B, C

How can I make a query that joins these three tables. The condition is that `Table A` must have a record.

I tried like this

```
select * from a
left join b on a.article_id = b.article_id
left join c on b.file_id = c.submission_id
where c.user_id = 6;
```

My query doesn't work in the case that `Table C` is missing a record. In that case, the join doesn't work for the three tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any criteria on the outer tables must be int he relevant ON clause, not the WHERE clause.

For example:

```
select * from a
left join b on a.article_id = b.article_id
left join c on b.file_id = c.submission_id and c.user_id = 6;
```

Comment: I think this is what he wants. Question was not all to clear though :]

Comment: Sorry about it, but the problem was with my approach. I have corrected the problem.

Comment: @Konerak, the lack of a WHERE clause int eh final query is a little suspicious, but I thought it was a safe answer because in my experience this is the most common problem I see in mysql questions on SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `LEFT JOIN`, then records from `a` and `b` are selected even if there are no corresponding records in table `c`. Use `INNER JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.article_id = b.article_id
INNER JOIN c ON b.file_id = c.submission_id
WHERE c.user_id = 6;
```

Comment: I have tried this but in the case that Table C is missing the match, it doesn't display the record.

Comment: 'The condition is that Table A must have a record'

Comment: @asdgfassagas decide what you want. Do you want **all** records from `a` anyway, and also records from `b` and `c` in case there are corresponding records? Then use Ike's answer.